# Can I connect all the available network printers without using a logonscript?

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, windows-server-2012, network-printer, printer

In our organisation we have around 30 printers an we are currently connecting for the user all the printers using a logon script that calls the command line app [con2prt](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181663)
 for a series of printers.

```
 con2prt /c %1
```

But this has the great problem that many user can stop the script and that means they end up not having all the printers available.

Can I connect all the available network printers without using the logonscript or the command line app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried *Print Services* of Windows Server?

[Technet: Windows Server Print Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448602.aspx)

Specific Instructions [here:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722179(v=ws.10).aspx)

> To install printers to groups of users or computers by using Group
>   Policy
>
> 1. Open the Administrative Tools folder, and then double-click **Print
>      Management.**
> 2. In the **Print Management** tree, under the appropriate print server,
>      click **Printers.**
> 3. In the results pane, right-click the printer you want to deploy, and
>      then click **Deploy with Group Policy.**
> 4. In the **Deploy with Group Policy** dialog box, click **Browse**, and then
>      choose a Group Policy object.
> 5. Click **OK**.
> 6. To assign the printer connection setting to the GPO, do one or both
>      of the following:
>
>    As a per-user setting, select the **The users that
>      this GPO applies to (per user)** check box.
>
>    As a per-machine setting, select the **The computers that this GPO
>      applies to (per machine)** check box.
> 7. Click **Add**.
> 8. Repeat steps 3 to 6 to add the printer connection setting to another
>      GPO.
> 9. Click **OK**.

Comment: I should point out that Windows Server Print Services are not required to do this. The GPOs can be created directly through Group Policy Management, and will achieve the same result.